# The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project @angular/cli@1.6.7

Tags: angular, angular-cli

`ng serve` command enter getting the above error.

> The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

I have already tried all StackOverflow answers, but could not resolve
my issue.

Also,

```
npm start command
User @angular/cli@1.6.7
```

my package.json file:

```
{
      "name": "headerfooter",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200",
        "build": "ng build --prod",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
        "@angular-package/change-detection": "^1.0.0",
        "@angular-package/core": "^1.0.1",
        "@angular/animations": "^8.1.1",
        "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.2",
        "@angular/common": "^8.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "^8.1.1",
        "@angular/core": "^8.1.1",
        "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
        "@angular/forms": "^8.1.1",
        "@angular/material": "^8.0.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.1.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.1.1",
        "@angular/router": "^8.1.1",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/angular": "^1.6.55",
        "angular-alert-module": "^2.0.3",
        "angular-encryption-service": "^0.1.0",
        "angular-star-rating": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
        "angular5-social-login": "^1.0.9",
        "angularfire2": "^5.2.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "config": "^3.2.0",
        "core-js": "^3.1.4",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "firebase": "^6.3.0",
        "http": "0.0.0",
        "intl-tel-input": "^16.0.2",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "md-autocomplete": "0.0.1-alpha.1",
        "ng-bootstrap-to-bootstrap-3": "^0.7.0",
        "ng-recaptcha": "^4.3.0",
        "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
        "ng2-tel-input": "^2.0.3",
        "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
        "ngx-echarts": "^4.2.1",
        "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.2.0",
        "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^2.2.1",
        "ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
        "ngx-show-hide-password": "^2.0.5",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "paytabs": "^2.2.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
        "primeng": "^8.0.1",
        "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
        "save": "^2.4.0",
        "sweetalert2": "^8.13.5",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.1",
        "@angular/cli": "^8.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.1.1",
        "@angular/language-service": "^8.1.1",
        "@types/googlemaps": "^3.37.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.13",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
        "@types/node": "^12.6.2",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "^4.2.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.0.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
        "protractor": "^6.0.0",
        "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
        "tslint": "^5.18.0",
        "typescript": "3.5.3"
      },
      "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 1.6.7.",
      "main": "app.js",
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
      },
      "author": "",
      "homepage": ""
    }
```

Comment: when i run ng serve command getting this error. The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

Comment: did you create the project through angular-cli or you cloned it from external source?

Comment: create the project through angular-cli approx 1 year ago

Comment: could you check all files like  main.ts  present

Comment: yes main.ts present

Comment: ok , please try `ng init` command inside your project and let me know whether it runs fine? @ManvendraSingh

Comment: Show us the folder structure and make sure you are in that project directory before hitting `ng serve` command

Comment: i am already project directory

Comment: getting this error The specified command ("init") is invalid. For a list of available options,
run "ng help" @VaibhavKumarGoyal

Comment: can you try `ng -v`?

Comment: did it work when you first created it?

Comment: you can try "ng update --all --force" and "npm install"

Comment: yes it's run my other pc but right now i am setup my code in new pc than i face this issue

Comment: yes i run both command it work fine 
npm install : after complete successfully get this message audited 15382 packages in 8.528s 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: ng -v not work but i am enter ng version its work @PrashantPimpale

Comment: `npm cache clean --force` and them do `npm i` again inside the project and test whether it runs @ManvendraSingh , sometimes the npm conflicts with the cached artifacts present

Comment: i try but same issue

Answer (score 0):

> The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a
>   project definition could not be found.

This error usually occurs, when **ng serve** command or **npm start** command is not run in the proper folder.

Please check the folder in which you are running the command properly. If your project is in `D://demo/MyFirstProject`, you must go to the folder "MyFirstProject" and then run the commands. If you run the command in the folder "demo", this error occurs.

Comment: Could you please do npm update and then run the application. This works in most of the cases